# How to implement push notifications using FCM for amazon kindle FireOS

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, kindle-fire

I have used `FCM` to implement Push notifications in react-native application for `IOS` and `Android` but could not get push notifications in `Amazon` kindle FireOS Tablets . how can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

FireOS is a fork of Android.  For Android, Firebase Push Notifications requires Google Play Services (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) which doesn't come on FireOS Tablets, but you can install it. To do so requires 4 apks - Google Account Manager, Google Services Framework, Google Play Services, and Google Play Store, as described in this article (https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/07/11/install-play-store-amazon-fire-tablet/).  Before I did this, debug from my app on a Fire tablet showed a Firebase error.  After adding Google Play, Firebase now initializes with no errors, "FirebaseApp initialization successful", but it still doesn't actually receive the push notifications.  So I'm assuming there is something required deeper in the OS stripped in the FireOS fork of Android.